# Deterministic Finite Automata state diagram

Tags: dfa

I need to make an 8-state DFA that takes 0s and 1s and has an even number of 1s and a substring of ...000... somewhere in it. So I know how to find a substring of 000 and I know how to find an even number of 1s, but I'm not sure how to put this together. Is there like a formula or something to follow for this, I just started DFAs and NFAs so I'm not quite sure how to solve this besides drawing it out with trial and error. Any help would be great

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it is best fitted for `cs.stackexchange.com` !!!

Answer (score 1):

For the testing even number of ones:

[image]

Then for testing the 000 substring:

[image]

Then we can compute the intersection of these DFA using the [classical cross-product construction](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/lkovacs/ATCSNotes/atcs_h2.pdf) and get the (minimal) DFA:

[image]